# convergence of series such that convergence of associative series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

for every integral $m \ge 2$, $\sum_{n=0} ^\infty (a_{nm+1}+...+a_{nm+m} )$ is convergence. then $\sum _{n=1} ^\infty a_n$ is convergence? I want to solve this. but i don't even know if the series converges.

Comment: You mean you don't know if the statement is true or wrong? It's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, such a sequence doesn't have to converge. Take for example

$$
a_n = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{ if $n$ is a prime $\ge 5$,}\\
-1, & \text{ if $n-1$ is a prime $\ge 5$,}\\
0,  & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

For any $m \ge 2, n\ge 0$, the term $s_{n,m}:=(a_{nm+1}+\ldots+a_{mn+m})$ contains at least 2 summands and starts with an index that is 1 more than a multiple of $m$ ends with an index that is a multiple of $m$.

Since the non-zero values of the sequence come at consecutive inidices and sum to $0$, the only way $s_{n,m}$ can be non-zero is if the last index is a prime $\ge 5$ or the first index is the successor of a prime $\ge5$.

But for any fixed $m\ge 2$, the former can only happen when $nm+m=(n+1)m$ is a prime, so $m$ must be a prime and $n$ must be $0$. The latter can only happen when $(nm+1)-1=nm$ is a prime, so $m$ must be a prime and $n=1$.

That means $s_{n,m}$ is non-zero at most for $n=0,1$. For a fixed $m$, that means $\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{n.m}$ converges, as the summands are guaranteed to be zero for $n\ge 2$.

That means the given sequence fullfills the conditions of the problem, but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ doesn't converge, because infinitely many $a_n$ are $\pm 1$ (there are infinitely many primes).